# Heroku Deployment Errors Not Allowing Discord.js Bot to Appear Online [NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error]

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js

I've recently been trying to deploy a very simple Discord.js bot with Heroku, but even though everything seems to build correctly, I just can't get it to appear online.

Here's the log from Heroku - I noticed the `NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL` error, and looked on here for answers. I changed the worker from `node index.js` to `node npm start` like suggested, albeit to no avail.

```
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 12.x...
       Downloading and installing node 12.19.0...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.8
       
-----> Restoring cache
       - node_modules
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json)
       audited 15 packages in 0.372s
       found 0 vulnerabilities
       
       
-----> Build
       
-----> Caching build
       - node_modules
       
-----> Pruning devDependencies
       audited 15 packages in 0.367s
       found 0 vulnerabilities
       
       
-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> worker
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 23M
-----> Launching...
       Released v7
       https://nira-chan.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

You can see on the Heroku application link that there's an error somewhere, but I've been looking for hours and I think I've just been staring at it hopelessly for too long.
I'm really new to coding, using a handful of online tutorials for this using Repl.it, so I do expect there to be mistakes scattered around.

Interestingly enough, it runs fine from Repl.it, so I'm thinking it's the json/Procfile that's causing the problems, but I honestly have no idea.
For now, I've posted the repository [here](https://github.com/anomalilies/Nira) if anyone knows how I can get it to run.

Thanks so much!

Comment: And `node index.js` and `node npm start` are both not working?

Comment: Yep, both won't work at all!

Answer (score 0):

Rewrote it all, and `service: npm start` worked for me, if anyone else is having the same problem!